# Cannot insert multiple records at a time with php and angular2

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

I'm trying to insert multiple records from selected checkboxes to mysql db with php. What is happening is after i post and go to check the db, i find all the records inserted in one line instead of each making a unique insertion. Below is the data is post in an array

```
["A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A","A","B","C","C","B","A","D","B","D","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C","B","B","A","A","A","C","B","B","D","C","C","C","B","D","D","D","D","D","C","D","C","A"]
```

PHP

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/catchapp.php'); ?>
<?php
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$uanswer= mysql_real_escape_string($data->useranswer);
  foreach ((array) $uanswer as $item) {
  mysql_select_db($database_catchapp, $catchapp);
  $insertSQL =  ("INSERT INTO user_answers (`uanswer`)VALUES('".$uanswer."')");
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $catchapp) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

JS

```
insert(){
for(var i=0;i<this.test.length;i++) {
  this.container.push(this.test['uanswer'+i]);
  } 

  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.container))
   this.http.post('http://localhost/catchapp/test/test_insert.php',{'useranswer':JSON.stringify(this.container)}).subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
mysql_select_db($database_catchapp, $catchapp);
foreach ((array) $uanswer as $item) {
  $insertSQL =  "INSERT INTO user_answers (`uanswer`)VALUES('".$item."')";
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $catchapp) or die(mysql_error());
}
```